# Список всех объектов класса

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, объекты

Требуется получить список всех ссылок на один класс (объекты Myclass могут находится в любых файлах; функция `print_all` находится в модуле, откуда импортируются классы)
Имеется класс и ссылки на него (`a`, `b`, `c` и 2 ссылки в `arr`, их и нужно получить)

```
class Myclass:
    pass

a = Myclass()
b = Myclass()
c = Myclass()
arr = [Myclass(), Myclas()]
```

```
def print_all():
    print(Myclass.__getall__())
```

выходные данные должны быть списком (можно кортеж, массив, главное чтобы можно было по элементам пробежаться):

```
[<__main__.Myclass object at 0x108a52e50>, <__main__.Myclass object at 0x108a52f10>, <__main__.Myclass object at 0x108a52fd0>, <__main__.Myclass object at 0x108a7e430>, <__main__.Myclass object at 0x108a7e400>]
```

Существует ли альтернатива вымышленной мною функции `__getall__`(как `GetAllActorsOfClass` в UE4) (возможно ли вообще впринципе получить список всех ссылок?)?

Comment: Почему бы в конструкторе класса не записывать `self`?

Comment: Можно пояснить?

Comment: При создании объекта сохранять ссылку куда-нибудь в один лист, чтобы потом можно было в `print_all` напечатать этот лист.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```py
class A:
    instances = []
    def __init__(self):
        self.__class__.instances.append(self)
    
    @classmethod
    def printInstances(cls):
        for instance in cls.instances:
            print(instance)

a = A()
b = A()
A.printInstances()

<__main__.A object at 0x6fffffd87cf8>
<__main__.A object at 0x6fffffd87d68>
```