# Создание привязки одного класса к другому Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы

Каким образом возможно сделать привязку класса к другому в Python? (чтобы привязанный класс всегда имел ссылку на основной) я просто хочу скопировать всю эту конструкцию при помощи `copy.deepcopy()`, можно ли это сделать только с родительским классом, так, чтобы все ссылки из образовавшихся вместе с ним привязанных классов вели именно к нему?
Пример (реальная ситуация специфична, но данный пример намного лучше иллюстрирует, то, что я хочу получить):
Допустим я хочу сделать программу, которая играет в шахматы. я Создал отдельные классы: `King`, `Piece`, `Board`. В `Board` все классы, которые надо привязать хранятся в списках.  Алгоритм программы - перебор вариантов. В классе `Board` функция `move()` такова, что изменяет объект, а не возвращает новый, измененный. Каждый раз, когда я хочу перебрать все возможные ходы, я выолняю:

```py
#code

for move in get_legal_moves(main_board, side):
   try_board = copy.deepcopy(main_board) #Все фигуры при копировании 
   try_board.move(move)                  #считают, что принадлежат не try_board, а main_board, 
                                         #из-за чего невозможно получить все возможные хода

#code
```

когда я выполняю `copy.deepcopy()` мне надо во всех появившихся объектах заменить ссылки на нужные. Можно конечно использовать функцию, но прописывать один и тот же алгоритм для всех классов, которые я собираюсь копировать - бред (названия переменных просто разные). Поэтому хочется чтобы это делалось как-то автоматически.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1145200/394322. Чем не подходит то, что я привёл в комментариях?

Comment: Тем что при `copy.deepcopy()` все ссылки останутся прежними. Они не будут ссылаться на новый класс, а продолжат ссылаться на старый

Comment: Думаю имеет смысл привести пример кода с желаемым поведением, так обычно всё становится понятней (по крайней мере мне). Используйте [кнопку править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1145526/edit).

Comment: зачем копировать клас ? может просто клепать объекты класса ?

Comment: Но `Car` не является для `Wheel` родительским классом, про который идёт речь в вопросе.

Comment: Я имею в виду родительский класс - класс к которому "привязываются" другие классы (извините, что непонятно объясняю)

Comment: В данном случае к классу `Car` должен привязаться класс `Wheel`

Comment: deepcopy в общем-то, не для такого нужен. Просто сделайте у Car метод copy, который будет выполнять именно нужную вам логику.

Comment: Вы неверно используете терминологию. Родительский класс, дочерний класс, подкласс - это все относится к наследованию. Почитайте, а затем исправьте вопрос, что бы не вводить в заблуждение людей. Ваш вопрос из другой области. PS: погуглите паттерн проектирования Фабрика. Возможно, это то, что вам нужно

Answer (score 2):

На основании этого и предыдущего вопросов, я понял задачу следующим образом:

- создание объектов `Wheel` разбросано по коду и не привязано к чему-либо: там два объекта, здесь три объекта и т.д.
- ссылки на все созданные объекты `Wheel` должны где-то храниться, чтобы по ним можно было пробежаться в цикле.
- ? объект `Wheel` должен иметь ссылку на объект в котором он используется, в данном случае `Car`.

  Однако в предыдущем вопросе был такой пример:

  ```
   a = Myclass()
   b = Myclass()
   c = Myclass()
   arr = [Myclass(), Myclass()]
  ```

  Что не вяжется с предыдущим утвержедением, так как в данном случае отсутствует объект-композитор (от слова composite - составной, комбинированный), указатель на который надо хранить...

**Можно сделать так:**

Класс `Wheel` хранит ссылки на свои экземпляры в атрибуте класса. Каждый экземпляр класса `Wheel` имеет ссылку на объект в котором он был создан. `name` в классе `Car` добавлено для наглядности.

```
import weakref

class Wheel:
    weakrefs_set = weakref.WeakSet()
    def __init__(self, car):
        self.__class__.weakrefs_set.add(self)
        self.car = car

class Car:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.wheels = [ 
                        Wheel(self),
                        Wheel(self),
                        Wheel(self),
                        Wheel(self)
                    ]

a = Car("Car_1")
b = Car("Car_2")

for wheel in Wheel.weakrefs_set:
    print(wheel, f"\tcar_name: {wheel.car.name}")
```

**Output**

```
<__main__.Wheel object at 0x7fecd7cbca20>   car_name: Car_1
<__main__.Wheel object at 0x7fecd7c77828>   car_name: Car_2
<__main__.Wheel object at 0x7fecd7c77860>   car_name: Car_2
<__main__.Wheel object at 0x7fecd7c77898>   car_name: Car_2
<__main__.Wheel object at 0x7fecd7cb64a8>   car_name: Car_1
<__main__.Wheel object at 0x7fecd7c778d0>   car_name: Car_2
<__main__.Wheel object at 0x7fecd7cc4908>   car_name: Car_1
<__main__.Wheel object at 0x7fecd7cc49e8>   car_name: Car_1
```

Похожий вопрос на английском: [Printing all instances of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/328851/2913477)